# How to set defaults for Border controls in custom block

Tags: block-editor

WordPress provides Border control for a block, if the block has support for it. By default, these Border controls are not set:

[image: Preview of Border controls in WordPress]

I have enabled a support for these controls in my block by adding the following code to `block.json`:

```js
...
"__experimentalBorder": {
    "color": true,
    "radius": true,
    "style": true,
    "width": true
}
...
```

To get saved values for these controls, I use the `__experimentalUseBorderProps`. Here is a code snippet of the edit function (`edit.js`):

```
import {
    useBlockProps,
    InnerBlocks,
    __experimentalUseBorderProps as useBorderProps
} from '@wordpress/block-editor';

export default function Edit() {
    const blockProps   = useBlockProps();
    const borderProps  = useBorderProps();

    return (
        <div { ...blockProps }
            style={ {
                ...borderProps.style,
            } }>
            <InnerBlocks />
        </div>
    );
}
```

However, I am wondering what is the correct way of setting default values for these controls. For example, `1px solid #000` as default border styles for the block.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if this is the right way for setting default values. But I'm able to set the default border values like this:

```
registerBlockType( 'block-name', {
...
    supports: {
        __experimentalBorder: {
            color: true,
            radius: true,
            style: true,
            width: true,
            __experimentalDefaultControls: {
                color: true,
                radius: true,
                style: true,
                width: true,
            },
        },
    },
    attributes: {
        style: {
            type: 'object',
            default: {
                border: {
                    color: '#000000',
                    radius: '10',
                    style: 'solid',
                    width: '1',
                },
            },
        },
    },
...
}
```

Please see for an example the 'color.background' 'style' section on this page:

> The block can apply a default custom background color by specifying its own attribute with a default e.g.:

https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/reference-guides/block-api/block-supports/#color-background